# Get current component name

Tags: angular

Is that possible to get current component name?

for example if I have `localhost:3000/en/mycomponent` and I'll to `this.router.url` it returns `/en/mycomponent` which is `/language/component`

I want to make redirect on language change.

I can make

`this.router.navigate([this.lang, my component here]);`

But how can I get current component from routing?

Comment: What is your exact requirement ? Its not clear through.your question. Can you explain?

Comment: It is possible to get component name. But what do you mean by current component name?

Comment: @micronyks current component name means that I want to detect in which component am I. I want to call it from service

for example if I'm in `/en/homecomponent` I want to get that name which is `homecomponent`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was running into the same issue as above and was able to use the following to retrieve the component name:
`this.route.routeConfig.component.name`.  This returned a string value that we can compare.

Comment: It does not work in production build since the name gets minified.

Answer (score 11):

Angular CLI:

You can access the component name from the constructor:

```
 console.log('this', this.constructor.name);

 this.constructor.name; // Component name
```

Comment: When you use this in production, you don't get the right result.

Comment: @herve Can I ask why you would do this in production? Seems like an implementation detail. I use it when debugging to see what component I'm looking at.

Comment: @Noumenon it's a very long story (and a problem of conception surely). I have 3 screens and I need to come back from the third to the first (for example) but the first can be one of 15 components and I need to be able to go back to the third that can be one of 11 other components.

Comment: Second the fact that this doesn't work in production. @Noumenon there could be a million reasons you'd want the name of the component. In my case, I was keeping track of which components had completed a certain initialization task

Answer (score 5):

You may get the component name like below,

```
export class MyComponent{

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    // Below will result in MyComponent
    console.log(this.route.component.name);         
  }
}
```

Having said that Routing is based on path rather the component name.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks for answer. As I see in the lates version of angularjs 2 this.route.component has no property name

Comment: @gsiradze what version of Router you are checking? See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/psTX5s0AxscXtw4aBnZ4?p=preview) . Check in crisis-list.component constructor. Cheers!!

Comment: I'm using latest version. maybe it's deprecated?

Comment: @gsiradze I ran into the same issue (intellisense putting red line under '.name', telling me it has no property 'name'). I dug into the route.component object and saw that it did indeed have a 'name' property, so I ran it despite intellisense telling me it was not a property, and my console correctly logged the component name.

Very weird. I'm hoping it's okay to keep this code, since it works, even though intellisense is telling me that it should not work. Perhaps that property doesn't get created until the application runs?

Comment: it seems to be always 'AppComponent'

Comment: @vuquanghoang is right, this tells you the component the URL routed you to, even if you call it in a subcomponent. The answer by Costly Developer is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

**Angular 8**

This returns name of current Component each time, the shown Component changes.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        if (val instanceof ActivationEnd) {
            console.log('componentName', val.snapshot.component['name']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect Method.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to get the component name is using the constructor.

```
this.constructor.name
```

Answer (score 3):

Only that component name isn't enough.. you may want the additional options and so on..

If the first segment is always your `language`, do it like this:

```js
let urlSegments = this.route.url.split('/');
urlSegments[1] = this.lang;
this.router.navigate(urlSegments.join('/'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current component name from the 'ActivatedRoute' module like this:

```
    const compName = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.component.name;
```

use the above either in onInit or constructor call. It's working fine in angular 6+. Not sure about the older versions.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but in a production build the name will differ from during dev, so don't use it for anything valuable

If you need to check 'which' component is currently in the route for example it's best to use typeof rather than checking for the name

```
const onComponent = typeof this.activatedRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.component === typeof MyCustomComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the component name with dot notation like that:

```
let state: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = routerState.root;

while (state.firstChild) {
  state = state.firstChild;
}

const stateComponent = <any>state.component;
const component = stateComponent ? stateComponent.name : '';
```

Comment: i am getting the correct name in local but when hosted in server i do not get the correct name what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

**To get the current component I use this code for Angular 13:**

```
import { ActivationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router'; 

constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
   if (val instanceof ActivationEnd) {
      const [,componentName] = val.snapshot.component.toString().split(" ");
      console.log(componentName);
   }
  });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

**@Madhu Ranjan answer.**

His approach will not work with dot notation.
We will get an error like, **Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.**

As it expects component to be string. As we used dot notation. On top of that, we are accessing a name string property on component string.

As dot notation expects everything to be string after dot. But here in
**route.component.name**    **(component.name is not a string)**. It will try to find component.name on route object.

So it's better to go with bracket notation in this case.It will evaluate and convert given expression to string.As component is a function on route object.

When I tried with:

```
console.log('current component rendered', route.['component']['name']);
                    or
console.log('current component rendered', route.component['name']);
```

I was successful in getting component name.